# Change colour of imageView programmatically

Tags: android, layout, imageview

I would simply like to change the colour of an imageView object using code, but it appears to be proving a lot more difficult than it sounds.

Here is my xml for the object:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/lifeSquare"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#2a80b9"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scaleType="fitStart" />
```

It's just a blue square, as you can see. I would like to be able to change this line in code:

```
    android:background="#2a80b9"
```

That's it!   I have read many posts on this topic, the most promising had the following solution:

```
View someView = findViewById(R.id.lifeSquare);
View root = someView.getRootView();
root.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#fffff"));
```

But it doesn't work. It just leaves the colour exactly as it is.

Has anyone done this before, or have any better ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why are you setting `background` of root view. Just this statement will work :

```
ImageView someView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.lifeSquare);
someView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Concern :

One more point is that your `imageView` has visibility `invisible` :

```
android:visibility="invisible"
```

Why are you setting invisible property to your imageview?

Comment: Because the image is not visible until the user does something........... I will test your code now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can save all your color hex codes in `color.xml` inside value folder of resources

```
imageView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
```

Answer (score 0):

refer this code:

```
imageView.setColorFilter(imageView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.desired_color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using hexcode for color and want to set the color as background of image, then this is the kotlin code.

```
    val bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(30, 30, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
    val colorCode = "#ffffff"
    canvas.drawColor(Color.parseColor(colorCode))
    mImageViewLogo.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
```